# html onclick event not firing

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I guess I am missing some fundamentals about html, javascript, DOM and propagation or anything like this, but I can't find any relevant question/answer.

Here is my code :

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function click(e) {
      alert(e.target.id);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="button" id="btn1" onclick="alert(event.target.id);" value="MyButton1">
  <input type="button" id="btn2" onclick="click(event);" value="MyButton2">
</body>

</html>
```

`MyButton1` is working fine. `MyButton2` isn't firing the onclick event.

The question is simple : why `MyButton2` isn't firing the event ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As there's a *click* method on the DOM element corresponding to the *button* element, name your function anything other than `click`:

```html
<html>  
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function clickMe(e) {
            alert(e.target.id);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
     <input type="button" id="btn1" onclick="alert(event.target.id);" value="MyButton1">
     <input type="button" id="btn2" onclick="clickMe(event);" value="MyButton2">
</body>
</html>
```

**Please note:** You should avoid using inline event handler, instead you can use `addEventListener()`:

```html
<html>  
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        document.getElementById('btn1').addEventListener('click', alertMessage);
        document.getElementById('btn2').addEventListener('click', alertMessage);
      });
      
      function alertMessage(e){
        alert(e.target.id);
      }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
     <input type="button" id="btn1" value="MyButton1">
     <input type="button" id="btn2" value="MyButton2">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you :) Is there any specification showing that `click` is kind of reserved function name ?

Comment: @Tuckbros, As there's a click method on the DOM element corresponding to the button element, you should not be using that:)

Comment: same is happening with `search`

Answer (score 0):

Or You could do this! Keeping you function name same!

Actually I would suggest to do this way(setting these attributes from the script)

```html
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <input type="button" id="btn1" onclick="alert(event.target.id);" value="MyButton1">
  <input type="button" id="btn2" value="MyButton2">

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function click(e) {
      alert(e.target.id);
    }
    
    document.getElementById("btn2").onclick = click;
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```